# MongoDB shell difference between show dbs and show databases

Tags: mongodb, console

As per [MongoDb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongo-shell/) the MongoDB shell command:

```
show dbs
```

> Print a list of all databases on the server.

and

```
show databases
```

> Print a list of all available databases.

I'm confused - from that what I read and understood these are not the same effect commands - right? **show databases** is not the alias of the **show dbs**?
There could be a database listed by **show dbs** which is not available and not listed by **show databases** is that right?

If so how it is possible that a database is on the server but is not available - access right of a user? is that what's behind **show databases** filtering?

Comment: In the default `mongo` shell these commands are identical, but this behaviour could be modified if you run any extra shell helpers. Your question suggests you might be seeing different output for the two commands? If so, I would try testing using `mongo --norc` to start a shell session without any potential extra files loaded. If you are seeing a difference it would be helpful to edit your question to include examples of how the output differs as well as the shell version (`version()`) and MongoDB server version (`db.version()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a difference between the two commands. Both of the operations call the `listDatabases` command with the same option.

Increasing the log level, the `show dbs` command logged:

```
2018-11-30T15:40:59.539-0800 I COMMAND  [conn23] command admin.$cmd appName: "MongoDB Shell" command: listDatabases { listDatabases: 1.0, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1543621253, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } }, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:708 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 22 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } } } protocol:op_msg 38ms
```

whereas `show databases` logged:

```
2018-11-30T15:41:01.722-0800 I COMMAND  [conn23] command admin.$cmd appName: "MongoDB Shell" command: listDatabases { listDatabases: 1.0, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1543621253, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000), keyId: 0 } }, $db: "admin" } numYields:0 reslen:708 locks:{ Global: { acquireCount: { r: 22 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r: 10 } } } protocol:op_msg 5ms
```

For reference, this is from MongoDB 3.6.7.

Comment: The most intuitive to me is that 'show dbs' is an alias of 'show databases' but got confused by different descriptions of them. Having log info about the same 'listDatabases' command I can believe they are in fact the same.